# Why do I have to replay the first level every time I open Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Every time I open the game, I have to restart at the first map. My characters and items save but not the gaming levels themselves. I can play level 2 if I do it right after beating level 1, but if I close the game only the level 1 map is available. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you playing offline? It could be an issue with the Steam Cloud syncing, you might need to disable the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

Found a fix [here](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?6389-UNACCEPTABLE-Level-Progress-NOT-SAVED-characters-NOT-SAVED&p=62641&viewfull=1#post62641), on the official forums.

> Right click on the game in steam -> Properties -> Verify game cache
>   When I did that it said "2 files failed to validate and will be reaquired"
>
> Then I restarted my game and got all my progress back. I never had the problem with deleted characters or lost items though. I was just unable to access levels I had unlocked. It might be a steam updating problem.

Comment: I get *"2 files failed to validate and will be reacquired"* every time I open/close the game.  It has fixed some multiplayer-related problems (not being able to join each others' games), though.